Sliding up (in & out) in Android 14 Animation
I have two activities and i want to make an animation in which when you click on a button in activity 1 it slide up out of the screen and opens activity 2 , and also in activity 2 there is a button when you click on it it slides up out of the screen and opens activity 1 .
so exiting an activity by going up out of the screen
and entering by going up into the screen .
which gives the feeling of scrolling .
So i started by making 2 activities and this anim folder that contains this tow animations sets:
slide_up_out.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>

slide_up_in.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>

And these are the two activities :
**
MainActivity.java**
package com.example.animationproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in,R.anim.slide_up_out);

            }
        });

    }

}

MainActivity2.java
package com.example.animationproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.Fade;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in,R.anim.slide_up_out);

            }
        });
    }

}

i tired it with API level 33 and 34 on the emulator it worked , but With My android14 Physcial device it does Something else .
Check the Videos here :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fF8OHnsE2fvZUDx9fuV_CErD1HgreBCf?usp=sharing
